# Will my B1/B2 visa become invalid if I quit my job?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I have a B1/B2 visa but I haven't travelled so far on it.

1. If I quit my current company, will the B1/B2 be still valid and can it be used for travel for another company?
2. If I relocate to another country, will the B1/B2 still be valid?

Comment: Is there a visa annotation printed on your visa that mentions your employer? Or some other specific reason for this question?

Answer (score 1):

1. A visitor visa remains valid until it expires or is cancelled. As long as you remain a genuine visitor and don't arouse the suspicion of border officers, it won't be cancelled unless you apply for a new visa.
2. Yes it will, your visa is not tied to where you live.